# CloudKit Permissions Failure

Tags: ios, objective-c, cloudkit

I'm getting the following message on running my App:

```
> "Permission Failure" (10/2007); server
> message = "com.company.ipadApp is not a valid Bundle ID for
> container iCloud.com.company.app"; uuid =
> xx; container ID =
> "iCloud.com.company.app">
```

I created an iPhone app and then made another target for an iPad app, and for it to use the same CloudKit container - I've checked the app ID on the developer panel and assigned the container to the new iPad app ID, but for some reason it's still telling me I've a 'Permission Failure'!

How do I get my iPad app to use the same container as the iPhone App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably should be a comment, but I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I am putting it here. I think there is a problem with CloudKit right now - see this thread: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/49003.

When I search for CloudKit and limit the results to the last 24 hours, the only results that come up are errors...

Comment: Looks like the issue was with CloudKit on Apple's side - I've not changed anything on my side and all of a sudden everything is working as it should!

Answer (score 1):

Have the same problem. Looks like Apple's server-side bug.
Try to disassociate and associate iCloud container again in AppID settings on Developer portal. After few minutes all should work.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need to do 2 steps,

1. Chose the container

[image]

2. The next is when you want to use the container within the app make sure you use

   ```
   let container = CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.com.THE ONE YOU WANT TO USE")
   let publicDB = container.publicCloudDatabase
   ```

In your first app that would have been

```
    let container = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, however I've already completed these steps - in objective-c I have (for step 2): CKDatabase *publicDatabase = [[CKContainer containerWithIdentifier:@"iCloud.com.company.myapp"] publicCloudDatabase]; - still get a permissions error!

Comment: What other steps did you take ? Have you changed anything else ?

Comment: I've kept everything else the same - I'm using the same view controller, and checked the query is returning zero results as a consequence of this permission error. I'm going to have to do some more digging and see..

Comment: I'd create a blank app and start from scratch and see if you can connect them.

Comment: To access public db use
let publicDB = CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.com.THE ONE YOU WANT TO USE").publicCloudDatabase